# 2017 macbook Trackpad is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, touchpad, macbook, macbook-pro

Hello and thank you in advance

I am currently attempting to run Ubuntu 20.04 on my 2017 macbook pro(13 inch with no touch bar ). I have mac os Catalina and windows 10 also installed.  The trackpad works fine in both Mac os and windows. Keyboard works fine in all 3 of the operating systems. The trackpad worked when I was in the installer but after it finished and I booted up the curser would not move. Works fine with a USB mouse. The trackpad did work once when I booted through recovery but after the first time it refused to work. Please advise and thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you on a mid-2017 Macbook Pro (Macbook14,1). I've installed Windows 10 through bootcamp and I have a linux partition also installed (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) which I triple boot with rEFInd 0.12.0. I wish someone would at least respond to you, kinda stinks. My trackpad worked for the first day then just quit for some reason in ubuntu. Hopefully we can get an adquate answer.

This is what I've found:

https://victorleungtw.com/2020/04/24/install-ubuntu-macbook-pro.html
https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver

Our macbook doesn't have the T2 chip (according to apple's T2 website), so use the drivers for the 12-inch Macbook. If you can get this to work, please get back to me.

EDIT:

I decided to be the guinea pig because I'm somewhat impatient. Turns out the drivers work! Here's the exact commands you'll need to use:

1. Open a terminal window and type `sudo -i` to become root.
2. Type the following commands:

   `echo -e "\n# applespi\napplespi\nspi_pxa2xx_platform\nintel_lpss_pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

   ```
    apt install dkms

    git clone https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver.git /usr/src/applespi-0.1

    dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
   ```

This worked for me about 20 mins ago. The only problem left is that it doesn't disable the trackpad when typing, so you may accindentally click something whilst typing using these drivers. I've seen a bug fix driver with keyboard detection included on github, so I'll try to find them again to post here.

Comment: Actually I found how to stop trackpad detection when typing. Use this command: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true

Comment: Can you point me to a guide to install ubuntu on my mid 2017 also is everything working on your MacBook Pro?